# Is it legal to keep garbage in any waste basket ? (Assuming properly sorted)

Tags: germany

Follow up to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/99373/38492), since there are fines to putting incorrectly sorted garbage into the dumpster, would it also be that it's illegal to throw waste in someone else's dumpster?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are using a public waste basket, which is allowed (unless you put something in there that does not belong, e.g. batteries, oil, generally dangerous goods), somebody is paying for that garbage, and people usually do not want to pay for other people's garbage.

To the best of my knowledge there is no specific law that makes this illegal, however there is the legal concept of "[Besitzstörung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besitzst%C3%B6rung)" - literally that means "disturbing someones property" (only that "property" might not cover the same legal details as the German "Besitz", because people do not usually literally own their dumpsters. However for most legal purposes have the same status as the owner). Using someone else's property without permission is not allowed. You can be fined, and if you somehow caused issues for the owners (e.g. again, if you dumped something illicit that leads to fines for the proper owners) you have to cover that as well.

So yes, that is illegal.

Comment: Is theft of services a crime in Germany? This might fall under that or a comparable crime along with what you mentioned.